# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_a^\infty \frac{dx}{1+n^2x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Compute

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_a^\infty \frac{dx}{1+n^2x^2}$$

the answer depends on whether $a>0$, $a=0$ and $a<0$.
How does this accord with the various convergence theorems?

Comment: Isn't this just $\lim_{n\to \infty} [\pi/2 - \arctan{(na)}]$?

Comment: Which is $0$ when $a>0$, $\pi/2$ when $a=0$ and $\pi$ when $a<0$.

Comment: Duly noted, I was just trying to get the OP to take it from there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int\limits_a^\infty\frac{dx}{1+(nx)^2}=\frac1n\int\limits_a^\infty\frac{ndx}{1+(nx)^2}=\left.\frac1n\arctan nx\right|_a^\infty=\frac1n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan na\right)\implies$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+n^2x^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac\pi2-\arctan na\right)=\begin{cases}\frac\pi2&,\,\,a=0\\{}\\\frac\pi2-\frac\pi2=0&,\;\;a>0\\{}\\\frac\pi2-\left(-\frac\pi2\right)=\pi&,\;\;a<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: You have a typo, it should be $\arctan(na)$.

Answer (score 1):

Making a change of variables $y = n x$:
$$
   n \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+n^2 x^2} = \int_{a n}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y^2}
$$
Hence 
$$
   \lim_{n \to +\infty} n \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+n^2 x^2} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{a n}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(n a) \right) = \begin{cases} 0 & a >0 \cr \frac{\pi}{2} & a = 0 \cr \pi & a <0  \end{cases}
$$